# Trig equations involving recip. ratios

Tags: trigonometry

what is the procedure for solving trig equations that involve a recip. ratio ?

For example, if $\csc\theta = -1$, what exactly do I do, if I know how to solve ones that involve just sine, cosine and tan.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try to describe the $csc$ function without using the words $sine, cosine,$ or $tangent$ (or their abbreviations) . see http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg/338px-Circle-trig6.svg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\csc \theta = \frac{1}{\sin \theta}$. Thus, we have
$$\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sin \theta} = -1\Bigg) \Longrightarrow \Bigg(1 = - \sin \theta\Bigg) \Longrightarrow \Bigg(\sin \theta = -1\Bigg),$$

giving us that $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

EDIT: a general procedure for solving equations with csc, sec, and cot is to sub in 1/sin, 1/cos, and 1/tan respectively, and then manipulate it into a solvable form.

Comment: So I can just solve it as sin = -1, and get the correct answer, yes ?

Comment: Yes, in this case.

Comment: This is because there is only one point on the unit circle where the y-value is $-1$; this is clear geometrically.